# Logging into the javascript console with WebDriver

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webdriver

Is it possible to log messages or DOM elements in the JavaScript console using the Selenium WebDriver? That would be very helpful for debugging my tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/logging), you can use it to show the log messages.

You can call the FireBug's log message javascript function through the web driver using [`execute_script`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html) or `execute_async_script`

Comment: That's great, thanks. Should also work with the embedded Google Chrome  JavaScript console, right?

Comment: Yes, if the executed JavaScript will print on the chrome console, calling the `execute_script` should have the same effect :)